# "Tu" em vez de "você" no sul do Brasil

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes, regionalismo, forma-verbal

No Rio Grande do Sul é bastante comum usar o "tu" no lugar do "você" na linguagem popular: *tu pode* (e não *tu podes*) em vez de *você pode*, por exemplo.

Qual a origem dessa substituição?

---

In the Rio Grande do Sul state, it's very common to use *tu* instead of *você* in everyday language: *tu pode* rather than *você pode*, for example.

Where did this substitution came from?

Comment: Na verdade, tu é a segunda pessoa do singular.

Comment: Maybe "where did this substitution come from and why doesn't the verb follow the correct conjugation for _tu_ (2nd person singular)"?

Comment: Sou do sul, e geralmente utilizo a conjugação correta, porém, realmente é utilizada de forma errada na maior parte dos casos.

Comment: Ouvi dizer também que o tu também é mais utilizado em portugal. confere?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth  "você" não é usado em Portugal, apenas "tu".

Comment: @Centaurus "você" é usado em Portugal, sim. Exemplo: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22voc%C3%AA%22+site%3A.pt Usamos tu para um tom familiar, de amizade próxima, ou informal. Usamos você para um tom formal.

Comment: @ANeves  Interessante.  Os usos variam de lugar para lugar.  No Rio de Janeiro, usamos você "para um tom familiar, de amizade próxima, ou informal."   "Tu" é muito informal, é mais usado por quem tem pouca instrução, que invariavelmente erra na concordância (tu vai, tu quer, tu sabe)  Já no Rio Grande do Sul, usa-se muito o "tu", e frequentemente sem errar a concordância.

Comment: @Centaurus Creio que na maioria dos lugares do país, "tu" soa formal, em vez de informal, especialmente quando conjugado corretamente. Há exceções, como no sotaque manezinho da ilha, onde se usa o "tu" com a terceira pessoa, e é o comum na fala popular.

Comment: @MateusFelipe   Discordo plenamente.  Em um ambiente formal, dirigir-se a alguém como "tu", pode soar como tentativa de ser íntimo.   E certamente, quem usa "tu" no Brasil, vai invariavelmente conjugar como terceira pessoa do singular, o que, demonstra falta de instrução. No Rio de Janeiro usamos sempre "você", "o senhor" ou "a senhora".  Noventa por cento de quem usa "tu", pertence àquela camada da população sem ou com pouca instrução, e não vai conjugar a segunda pessoa do singular corretamente,

Comment: PS  Desconheço o que significa "sotaque manezinho da ilha".

Comment: @Centaurus Talvez essa seja a realidade em alguns lugares, mas não na maioria do país, já que na maioria do país o pronome "tu" caiu em desuso e não se usa na fala popular. Isso é exceção em alguns lugares, como o citado por você Rio de Janeiro, ou o Rio Grande do Sul. Mas nesses lugares onde o "tu" caiu em completo desuso, como na região do Paraná onde eu nasci, ou em São Paulo, o "tu" acaba sendo considerado muito formal.

Comment: @MateusFelipe   Continuo discordando. Dirigir-se a uma senhora na rua usando o pronome "tu" pode até ser considerado "falta de educação"..  Mas essa é a minha experiência de vida, não só no Rio de Janeiro.  Contudo, não me considero o "dono da verdade" e, se alguém já fez ou vier a fazer um estudo a respeito, com um protocolo "flawless", aceito o resultado seja ele qual for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A conjugação verbal do modo imperativo no português moderno, às vezes, incomoda quem conhece a gramática tradicional, principalmente quanto se trata do uso de tu e você.

**Por exemplo:**

> - lê ou leia?
>
> *Você quer saber bem o assunto, então leia este livro*. Usou o tratamento você (3.ª pessoa) e o verbo ler ficou leia (3.ª pessoa do modo imperativo). Houve uniformidade de tratamento.
>
> *Tu queres saber o assunto, então lê este livro*. Usou o tratamento tu (2.ª pessoa) e o verbo ler ficou lê (2.ª pessoa do modo imperativo). Houve uniformidade de tratamento.
>
> *Você quer saber bem o assunto, então lê este livro*. Usou o tratamento você (3.ª pessoa) e o verbo ler ficou lê (2.ª pessoa, tu). Não houve uniformidade de tratamento. Isso não é tolerado pela gramática tradicional.

O português moderno permite que se escolha livremente entre tratá-lo por tu ou por você. Nas gramáticas tradicionais, são duas formas igualmente corretas para tratar a segunda pessoa do discurso: 1.ª pessoa: quem fala (eu-nós)/ 2.ª pessoa: com quem se fala (tu-vós, você-vocês)/ 3.ª: de quem se fala (ele-eles, ela-elas).

Embora tu e você se refiram à segunda pessoa do discurso, tu pertence à 2.ª e você pertence à 3.ª pessoa gramatical, exigindo as formas verbais e os pronomes respectivos.

Mas o rumo evolutivo da língua aponta a supremacia absoluta do você e a retirada de cena de tu/vós. A conjugação verbal se reduzirá a quatro pessoas: eu, ele, você; nós, eles, vocês.

Para fazer um convite, uma exortação, ou dar uma ordem usa-se o imperativo, mas no português moderno misturam-se imperativo e subjuntivo.

Veja a antiga propaganda da Caixa Econômica Federal "Vem pra Caixa você também!". Vem é o tu do imperativo. Para haver uniformidade, deveria ser "Venha pra Caixa você também!"

Comment: Boa resposta.  No sul do Brasil pelo menos muitas pessoas usam o "tu" corretamente.  No Rio de Janeiro, aqueles que usam "tu" conjugam-no erradamente.  Eu diria que talvez 30% dos cariocas usam o "tu" em conversação, e 100% desses conjuga o "tu" como se fosse "você".  Não se ouve por aqui "tu sabes" ou "tu queres" e sim "tu sabe" e "tu qué".  Ainda bem que a maioria usa você.  O "tu" é visto por muitos cariocas como indicativo de pouco respeito e muita intimidade, mesmo quando usado corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Em português, "tu *pode*" está incorreto gramaticalmente, ainda que possa ser utilizado em algumas regiões.

A conjugação correta do verbo *Poder* é a seguinte:

Eu *posso*

Tu *podes*

Ele *pode*

Nós *podemos*

Vós *podeis*

Eles *podem*

[Referência](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/poder)

Comment: O autor da pergunta sabe disso, tanto que ele deixou claro que o termo caiu nas graças da "linguagem popular". A pergunta dele pede explicações de como que isso foi acontecer.