# É correto usar "vocês" em vez de "vós"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, conjugações, pronomes, vós

Muitas vezes usei *vocês* numa frase em vez de *vós*, que eu considero mais correto, realmente. Usei o primeiro porque muitas vezes é mais fácil conjugar o verbo, porque aparece na terceira pessoa do plural (tipo que acaba em *-em*), em vez de conjugar o verbo na segunda pessoa do plural com *vós*, que nem sempre é fácil de fazer.

Tirando um exemplo ao acaso: *Vocês fazem isso?* em vez de *Vós fazeis isso?*

Neste caso o verbo fazer não é difícil de conjugar (porque essa conjugação aparece muito recorrentemente) na segunda pessoa do plural, mas existem casos, por exemplo:

> *Porquê vocês se riem?* em vez de *Porquê vos rides?*

Dos quais poderia ter dúvidas sobre a correção da conjugação do verbo que estou usando (ou *a usar*?): não neste caso porque controlei. Já agora, acho que deveria usar mais logicamente *estou usando* em vez de *que estou a usar*.

As minhas perguntas são as seguintes:

1. O meu uso de *vocês* está correto, ou seja posso usá-lo em vez de *vós*? Se não, porquê? Ou existe algum diferença semântica entre *vocês* e *vós*?
2. Se sim, *vocês* é usado só em Portugal ou por exemplo também se usa no Brasil?
3. Só eu tenho esta dificuldade em conjugar alguns verbos, sobretudo aqueles que acabam em *-ir*, na segunda pessoa do plural?
4. Mesmo que *vocês* esteja correto, deveríamos usar *vós*? Na minha opinião sim, porque efetivamente *vós* existe por um motivo.

Eu vivi 13 anos em Portugal mas entretanto mudei para outro país onde aprendi outra língua, que considero a minha outra língua mãe, mesmo não sabendo falá-las sempre perfeitamente, como neste caso.

Sugestões para aprender a conjugar sempre bem os verbos são bem aceites.

Comment: Já não é tão comum quanto antes. Deixo 3 perguntas relacionadas que podem ajudar a perceber o problema: [Why is “vós” rarely used today?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/390/why-is-v%c3%b3s-rarely-used-today?s=1|0.9834), [Qual é a etiqueta no uso de «vós podeis, vós sabeis», etc. no norte de Portugal?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/qual-%c3%a9-a-etiqueta-no-uso-de-v%c3%b3s-podeis-v%c3%b3s-sabeis-etc-no-norte-de-portugal?s=2|0.8454) e [“Tu” em vez de “você” no sul do Brasil](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/111/tu-em-vez-de-você-no-sul-do-brasil).

Comment: No Brasil, raramente usamos a segunda pessoa: apenas na leitura de livros antigos ou no aprendizado da língua portuguesa. Sempre utilizamos a terceira pessoa nesses casos.

Comment: O comentário de @StriterAlfa refere-se ao uso coloquial da língua.

Comment: @Mindwin - De forma alguma. "Vós" não é jamais usado no padrão culto brasileiro. Não há reportagem de jornal, trabalho acadêmico, nem sentença de juiz que faça uso desse arcaísmo. Usam-se exclusivamente pronomes de tratamento, principalmente "você" e "o senhor" / "a senhora". "Vós" é utilizado exclusivamente no registro literário - e mesmo aí é raro.

Comment: @LuísHenrique DUZIAS de sentenças do judiciario usam a segunda pessoa do plural "Vós" e conjugações relacionadas. Basta rápida busca para trazer algumas sentenças atuais. E estou falando do judiciário brasileiro.

Comment: @Mindwin Caso em que você terá a gentileza de colocar os linques.

Comment: @LuísHenrique "linques"??? atalho, hiperligacao, url, endereço, fonte, citação. o neologismo de que fazes uso soa crasso, é pouco usado e trata-se de anglicanismo desnecessário.

Comment: @LuísHenrique [Manual de Redação do Tribunal do Trabalho, página 42](https://portal.trt11.jus.br/images/arquivos/manual_red.pdf)  expressamente recomenda aos juízes e demais seguidores do documento que utilizem a segunda pessoa (tu, vós). O documento supra está em uso e é atual.

Comment: @Mindwin o manual não dá essa recomendação. O capítulo que você mencionou apenas explica a como funciona a concordância na língua portuguesa.

Comment: Complementando o que o @erickrf comentou: nas páginas 44-45 do mesmo manual, recomenda-se o uso dos pronomes de tratamento (em terceira pessoa) em comunicação direcionada aos servidores do Poder Judiciário.

Comment: Essa seria uma boa pergunta, se fosse uma pergunta. Mas como o autor da pergunta não quer resposta, apenas validação da sua própria posição, -1.

Answer (score 18):

1. Não há nada de errado em usar *vocês* (ou *os senhores*, *Vossas Excelências*, etc.) para referir os interlocutores, desde que se usem também as formas verbais e pronomes da 3ª pessoa. O que é estruturalmente discutível é usar *vocês* com os pronomes e determinantes *vos*, *vosso* e *convosco*, como se faz em Portugal (mas não no Brasil). No entanto, trata-se de um desvio mais que legitimado pelo uso.

   Se chegares com alguém a uma balcão de uma pastelaria, podes ouvir qualquer destas duas:

   > (1) Posso ajudar-**vos**?
   >   (2) Posso ajudá-**los**?

   Num contexto informal, ouvirias invariavelmente (1).

   Mas será bem mais raro ouvir (4) em lugar de (3):

   > (3) Não me posso esquecer de **vos** dar o **vosso** saco.
   >   (4) Não me posso esquecer de **lhes** dar o **seu** saco.

   Quero dizer que não trocar *lhes* por *vos* e *seu* por *vosso* é bastante incomum.
2. *Vocês* usa-se em ambos os países, mas *vós* não se usa de todo no Brasil. Em Portugal, o uso é restrito a grande parte do Norte e algumas zonas do centro. Mesmo nessas regiões, por vezes terminações da 2ª pessoa do plural ocorrem com *vocês* ou *vós* ocorre com terminações da 3ª pessoa.
3. A maioria das pessoas em regiões onde não se usa *vós* não sabem conjugar os verbos com vós, especialmente verbos irregulares (a maioria dos quais são verbos com infinito monossilábico que têm ainda desinências pré-século XVI com *-des*/*-de*). Nota que não são apenas verbos com *-ir*; *crer* também é irregular, por exemplo.

   No entanto, a maioria dos falantes não terá dificuldade em reconhecer as formas com *vós*.
4. Não entro por aí :)

Comment: *Vós* é a segunda pessoa do plural nas conjugações verbais, o que seria então *vocês*?

Comment: @JorgeB. a terceira pessoa, talvez? "Vocês são", "vocês fazem". (Mas em "façam vocês", já é segunda... Nem sei o que achar.)

Comment: Uma complementação inversa que não responde à pergunta do autor mas que talvez seja de interesse geral, em algumas regiões do Brasil faz-se essa confusão também no uso do "tu". Pelo menos onde eu vivi, se usa o "tu", que deveria conjugar-se em segunda pessoa, mas com a conjugação em terceira pessoa. Por exemplo: em vez de "tu viste como o céu está lindo, hoje?", diz-se "tu viu como o céu está lindo, hoje?". Em alguns casos, uma corruptela também é usada: "tu visse como o céu está lindo, hoje?"

Answer (score 3):

*Você* é um pronome de tratamento e deve ser usado com a conjugação da terceira pessoa (ele).

Tem origem no [*vossa mercê*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voc%C3%AA), que era um pronome de tratamento exclusivo para a realeza. Em uma época onde não era permitido, ou pelo menos não de bom tom, a uma pessoa comum se referir diretamente a um rei. Por isso, dirigia-se ao rei como *vossa mercê*, "aquele que está sob vosso controle", que em último caso, era o próprio rei, o qual só deve obediência (somente) a si próprio).

Embora tenha, com o passar do tempo, se popularizado, não possui de maneira alguma origem vulgar. Portanto, não é diminuidor no trato com seu interlocutor. 
  ...salvo, caso o interlocutor tenha a monarquia como objeto de desprezo.

Comment: Embora seja boa informação, não percebo como é que isto responde a `É correto usar “vocês” em vez de “vós”?`.

Comment: Não existe resposta sobre o que é correto. Podemos dar insumos para ele decidir o que será, segundo ele próprio, mais adequado de acordo com a situação.

Comment: Eu creio que *mercê* no contexto original do *vossa mercê* significa 'favor, benefício, magnanimidade', e tu dirigias-te à magnanimidade do rei, para que ele te concedesse o que lhe pedias, penso eu. 'Sob controle de' é na expressão *à mercê de* ('dependente da magnanimidade, ou falta dela, de'?) o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/merc%C3%AA) traz estes significados todos, mas não explica o significado específico de *mercê* no *vossa mercê*.

Answer (score 0):

No português do Brasil, eu diria que "vocês" não só é correto, mas que é o único uso correto. "Vós" é arcaico e não pode ser usado, exceto no padrão literário ou em fórmulas fixas como o Padre Nosso e alguns juramentos, a não ser como galhofa. Em Portugal entendo que ainda se usem as formas oblíquas, com "vocês" caso reto, como fazemos com a segunda pessoa do singular no Brasil ("você esqueceu teu caderno"), mas no Brasil nem isso, e soaria ridículo para a imensa maioria das pessoas, inclusive as cultas. E aquilo que soa inaceitável para a totalidade ou quase totalidade dos falantes é... gramaticalmente errado.

Comment: não é uma lei, é a maneira como a língua é falada. Vós não se usa mais, e é rejeitado pela imensa maioria dos falantes. Portanto, é arcaico. Você pode achar estúpida e errada a língua portuguesa tal como é falada, mas isso não muda o fato de que é assim que ela é falada. Quanto à lógica, também havia uma razão para que o Latim tivesse três gêneros em vez de dois, e  seis diferentes casos gramaticais, os quais todos se tornaram arcaicos e deixaram de existir. Foi estúpido acabar com eles? Pode ser, mas eles acabaram e não vão ser ressuscitados - nem eles nem o pronome vós.

Comment: "Em Portugal entendo que ainda se usem as formas oblíquas, com 'vocês' caso reto". Não me parece que seja ""**ainda se usem**"; quando muito é "**já se usam**""; imagino que esse uso tivesse no passado sido condenado, mas já já está consolidado há muito. Até já se ouve pessoas dizer coisas do tipo, "tenho uma coisa para vós; vocês nem adivinham o que é".