# Origem e significado de “Vossa Mercê”?

Tags: origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

Já toda a gente sabe que “Vossa Mercê” foi um pronome de tratamento que o pessoal usou, primeiro, para se dirigir ao rei, depois aos nobre mais importantes, depois aos menos importantes, até que passou a ser para toda gente que não tivesse direito a um pronome mais pomposo. Entretanto, ou depois, nãos sei bem, *vossa mercê* passou a *vossemecê*, a *vosmecê* , e a *você* ([Wikipedia, “você”](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voc%C3%AA)).

Agora a minha primeira questão é, quando é que *Vossa Mercê* começou a ser usado? A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voc%C3%AA) diz que foi no século XV, mas não dá mais pormenores nem avaliza com fonte fiável.  Eu gostaria de saber qual é o registro mais antigo do uso de *Vossa Mercê*.

Depois, isto foi criação nossa, ou foi importado? Por exemplo do castelhano ou francês, ou adaptado do *Your Grace* da fala comum de Westeros?

Finalmente, qual era o significado original de *mercê* em *Vossa Mercê*? Vou já avançar várias hipóteses:

1. [*Mercê* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/merc%C3%AA) significa ’favor, benefício, concessão de uma graça’. Então, e foi o que primeiro me veio à cabeça, uma pessoa ao dirigir-se à mercê do rei, seria como dirigir-se à magnanimidade, benevolência dele, tal como depois vieram a dirigir-se à majestade e alteza dele, ou à excelência, eminência ou santidade de outras pessoas.
2. Depois lembrei-me que apareceu a certa altura a doutrina do [“direito divino dos reis” (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direito_divino_dos_reis), segundo a qual o rei reina por direito concedido por Deus, ou seja, por mercê concedida por Deus. Então a mercê na pessoa do rei a que as pessoas se dirigiam seria a mercê que (segundo alguns) o rei tinha recebido de Deus?
3. Vi uma outra sugestão [nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/%C3%89-correto-usar-voc%C3%AAs-em-vez-de-v%C3%B3s/3674#comment15687_3674)—que *vossa mercê* significaria ’aquele que está à vossa mercê’, que seria o próprio rei—mas não fiquei muito convencido.

**Resumindo:** qual é primeiro uso conhecido de *Vossa Mercê*, donde é que aquilo veio, e qual era o significado daquele *mercê*?

Comment: [Relacionado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/836/457).

Comment: @tchrist, muito interessante. Não imaginava que *usted* fosse primo de *você*.

Comment: Também duvido que *usted* fosse o primeiro, mas que ambos (e outros) tivessem uma origem comum através de uma forma de tratamento compartilhada e mais ou menos equivalente em todas as línguas românicas do Ocidente e até mesmo as da Itália. Deve ter havido algum "acordo" na Península Ibérica, já que agora temos muitas palavras semelhantes em todas as línguas de lá: *você* no português, *vostede* no galego, *usted* no castelhano, *(v)usté* no asturiano, *vostè* no catalão, etc. Tratamentos antigos como *Vossa Excelência* ainda são usados na linguagem diplomática para embaixadores, certo?

Comment: @tchrist, sim, claramente origem comum. *Vossa Excelência* é usado até para além da diplomacia. A [Gramática online Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap09-03-pronomes_de_tratamento) descreve o uso no Brasil) ("Emprego dos pronomes de tratamento da 2ª pessoa", ponto 2 "tratamento cerimonioso"); A Gramácita em papel do Cunha e Cintra (em que se baseia o Aulete), diz que em Portugal é ainda mais usado; mas é um bocado fora dos meios em que me movo.

Comment: @tchrist, relendo isto, talvez tenha havido uma falha de comunicação: no meu primeiro comentário, quis dizer "não imaginava que *usted* fosse primo ('cousin') de *você*".

Comment: Lembro-me de uma vizinha utilizar "eei meces" em substituição de voce ou tu.

Comment: @ClMend, "eei meces"? isso seria uma modificação de *vossas mercês"? Onde foi isso?

Comment: Na ilha da Madeira. Já caiu completamente em desuso. Quem usava era  uma pessoa que nasceu no início do século 20.

Comment: vuestra merced (espanhol) + vossa mercê {graça ou concessão) (português) que no inglês deu: Your grace.

Comment: @Lambie, pois, se vires os comentários acima, nomeadamente do tchrist, já tínhamos chegado a essa conclusão. Mantém-se a pergunta de quando e onde é que isso surgiu.

Comment: @Jacinto, não me pareceu **tão** claro.

Comment: @Jacinto, creio que pronomes de tratamento têm as primeiras letras em caixa alta. Ref.:https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf46.php.

Comment: @Schilive, verdade; editei.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente gostaria de adicionar que me baseei principalmente em apenas um texto, o que enfraquece o texto, mas, em simultâneo, usei uma pesquisa aparentemente confiável.

#### Origem

De acordo com Teyssier [2] (p. 29), em galego-português (1200–1350), desconhecem-se as formas de tratamento concordantes com a 3ª pessoa (exs.: “sabe”, “giram”). De acordo com Carlos Elberto Faraco, o primeiro registro de “Vossa Mercê” é de 1331.

No latim, principalmente depois de 300, aos imperadores romanos se tratava com “*vestra*” + ‘*Serenitas*’, ‘*Claritudo*’, ‘*Maiestas*’, ‘*Excellentia*’, ou ‘*Alternitas*’; formas que viveram à Idade Média e têm relação com pronomes de tratamento hodiernos. A semelhança de estrutura com “Vossa Mercê” é bem aparente, principalmente por “*vestra*”, que é traduzido para “vossa”.

Assim, Faraco diz que “Vossa Mercê” e “Vossa Senhoria” têm certamente origem medieval, tendo “Mercê” relação com “a mercê do rei, relacionada particularmente com a distribuição da justiça e com a proteção real”.

Faraco também diz que não há certeza em relação ao ponto de origem de “Vossa Mercê” e “Vossa Senhoria”, mas a suposição é de que “Vossa Mercê” é de origem ibérica e “Vossa Senhoria”, de italiana (“*Vostra Signoria*”).

#### Uso

“Vós” era o pronome usado para se referir ao rei, mas, com o crescente poder da burguesia e de sua representatividade na corte, o rei se tornava uma figura única, mais importante, poderoso e influente. Assim surge uma pressão à língua para se adaptar, e, no século XV, surgem vários modos de se tratar ao rei, sendo a mais antiga “Vossa Mercê”. Outras delas são “Vossa Senhoria” (1434), “Vossa Majestade” (1442), Vossa Alteza (1450) e “Vossa Excelência” (1455). Interessante notar a semelhança destas formas com as formas latinas supraditas.

Provavelmente no início do século XV, os burgueses se travam com “Vossa Mercê” e começava a haver uma preferência de “Vossa Alteza” para se referir ao rei. Esta tabela apresenta a freqüência de uso dentre “Vossa Alteza”, “Vossa Senhoria” e “Vossa Mercê”:

[image: Tabela de freqüência de uso dentre “Vossa Alteza”, “Vossa Senhoria” e “Vossa Mercê”]

Um decreto de 1597 tentando fixar o uso dos pronomes de tratamento, diz, como nota, que “Vossa Mercê” pode ser usado no fechamento duma carta. Faraco conclui que a forma já não possuía mais valor honorífico, mas matinha o de respeito. Faraco também diz ser isso um indício de ser uma forma de uso social amplo, apontando as peças de Gil Vicente como outro indício.

Durante XVII–XVIII, a forma “Vossa Mercê” começou a se arcaizar, enquanto “você” ganhava força.

Faraco diz que o primeiro registro de “você” é de 1666. Porém, também diz que, principalissimamente no Brasil, havia várias formas paralelas. Isto se dá pela rápida evolução fonética de “Vossa Mercê” a “você”.

Alguns exemplos de formas paralelas são “Vossemecê” e “Vosmecê”. Interessante notar que, em um texto de provavelmente por volta de 1920 que estava na prova oficial do 9º ano do Estado de SP, o autor usa “Vosmecê” em uma situação inteiramente informal.

#### Notas Finais

Eu me baseei completamente em um trabalho de Carlos Elberto Faraco (https://revistas.ufrj.br/index.php/lh/article/view/17150/10437) de incríveis 22 páginas, salvo quando citei Teyssier, no último parágrafo e parte do penúltimo parágrafo. Por isso, ele tem o crédito de tudo aqui dito.

O texto que fiz é uma parcela do trabalho de seu trabalho, que pouco reinforma coisas. Então, recomendo muitissimamente a leitura do trabalho de Faraco, onde ele responde de verdade à pergunta de Jacinto duma forma não complicada. Por isso talvez a minha resposta seja mais uma cópia do que uma resposta real.

---

1 — https://revistas.ufrj.br/index.php/lh/article/view/17150/10437

2 —  https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/158086/mod_resource/content/1/TEYSSIER_%20HistoriaDaLinguaPortuguesa.pdf

Comment: O artigo do Faraco é muito interessante. Ainda gostaria de ver esse tal primeiro uso conhecido de *Vossa Mercê* de 1331, e compreender melhor o significado de *mercê*. Dei uma vista de olhos superficial no [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](https://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt//), não o encontrei o primeiro registro, mas encontrei na *Crónica Geral de Espanha* (cerca de 1350)  com frequência *vossa mercê*, mas não como pronome de tratamento; aparece em frases do tipo "se for vossa mercê conceder-me isto ou aquilo", onde *mercê* parece poder ser interpretado como ’bondade, magnanimidade’.

Comment: @Jacinto, depois da minha pesquisa de 40 minutos, que não é muito tempo, não o encontrei. Um artigo referenciava diretamente a um manuscrito de 1331 referente à Corte, então, creio que o primeiro registro esteja presente num manuscrito físico não digitalizado.

Comment: @Jacinto, encontrei a frase desse texto em espanhol. Esse “se for vossa mercê” pode ser algo como “se for vossa vontade” ou “se for, Vossa Mercê, [...]” (vocativo), já que a pontuação da época é bem diferentes da hodierna e lembrando de “à mercê de”. Alguns “sites” dizem que “Vossa Mercê” nasceu na Espanha e, então, foi para Portugal. Logo faria sentido ver primeiro num texto espanhol do que num português. Mas não sou lingüísta, então, não me leves 100% a sério, por favor.

Comment: Frascamente! Eu vi o contexto: não é vocativo; ’vontade’ até faz sentido, pelos menos nalguns exemplos), mas ’bondade, magnanimidade’ está mais próximo do significado de *mercê* . A "Crónica Geral de Espanha" é em português, composto originalmente em português, pelo Conde de Barcelos, filho natural do rei português D. Dinis (Espanha designa aqui toda a península). Encontrei este [Sobre la génesis de 'Vossa Mercê' en el português medieval](https://www.academia.edu/13566801/Sobre_la_g%C3%A9nesis_de_Vossa_Merc%C3%AA_en_el_portugu%C3%A9s_medieval), que deve ser interessante.

Comment: A frase que encontraste é "E eu venhome pera vos e, se for vossa mercee,quero seer vosso vassallo"? Isto é português medieval, precisamente da "Crónica Geral de Espanha".

Comment: @Jacinto, sim, foi essa. https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/9403/1/ulfl144050_tm.pdf

Comment: @Jacinto, eu achei que fosse espanhol, mas é português, obrigado. Eu li o pedaço contendo o texto em português: “En otras palabras, Vossa Mercê
en (2) es una construcción de 3P — Vossa + nombre — que corresponde semanticamente a tu voluntad”. O texto (2) é “ Senhor, (...), por que dixe ao concelho que vos desse a villa, quiserõme matar os filhos d'Airas Gonçallo, assi
como vistes. E eu venhome pera vos e, se for vossa mercee, quero seer vosso vassallo. (CdP, Crônica Geral de
Espanha, 1344)
Señor, porque le dije al concejo que os diese la villa, [...]”. Interessante. Obrigado pelo texto.

Answer (score 0):

Não há um consenso sobre o início de tal expressão. Existem autores que diga que em meados de 1357 a 1433, os Aristocratas já se tratavam com "vossa mercê), no entanto também existem aqueles que digam que mesmo em meados dos séculos XIV e XV esse termo ainda não havia se firmado como expressão pronominal.

Comment: Derli, bem-vindo ao site. Isso que dizes é potencialmente muito interessante, mas precisa de mais pormenores e de ser fundamentado. Quem são esses autores. Em que é que te apoias para afirmar isso? Podes indicar algumas fontes? E esses autores baseiam-se em quê? Se dizem que em 1357 os aristocratas se tratavam por *vossa mercê*, há documentos desse ano onde figura essa forma de tratamento?